# How to use vim as an error checker?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I'm transitioning to vim and I love the feature other IDEs provided in which when I wrote something with a syntax error it accuses me through a red underlining.

I don't know what this type of feature is called.
Can someone hint me how to make that work?

I'm coding in ruby.

What I'm looking for I think is called linter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's needed for solving the problem

https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic

Comment: Thats one possible choice. I use ale. But the gist of the answer is basically a plugin, unless you want to do the heavy lifting yourself.